# Stack-safe unfold

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to write an unfold for streams.

Fails to compile, because it's not tail recursive.

```
@annotation.tailrec
def unfold[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Option[(A, B)]): Stream[B] =
  f(a).map { case (a, b) => b #:: unfold(a)(f) }.getOrElse(Stream.empty)
```

... not really working either. (Not lazy)

```
def unfold[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Option[(A, B)]): Stream[B] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(state: A, next: Stream[B]): Stream[B] = {
    f(state) match {
      case Some((a, b)) => go(a, b #:: next)
      case None => Stream.empty
    }
  }
  go(a, Stream.empty)
}
// unfold: [A, B](a: A)(f: A => Option[(A, B)])Stream[B]
unfold(0)(i => Some((i+1, i))).take(10).toList
// java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
//   at .$anonfun$res3$1(<console>:18)
//   at .$anonfun$res3$1$adapted(<console>:18)
//   at $$Lambda$1543/299219071.apply(Unknown Source)
//   at .go$1(<console>:19)
//   at .unfold(<console>:24)
//   ... 27 elided
```

Kinda ugly, via `Iterator`.

```
def unfold[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Option[(A, B)]): Stream[B] = {
  new Iterator[B] {
    private var state: Option[A] = Some(a)
    private var nextResult: Option[B] = None

    def next: B =
      nextResult.getOrElse(
        throw new NoSuchElementException("next on empty iterator"))

    def hasNext: Boolean = {
      if (nextResult.isDefined) {
        true
      } else {
        state match {
          case Some(s) =>
            f(s) match {
              case Some((nextState, produced)) =>
                nextResult = Some(produced)
                state = Some(nextState)
                true
              case None => false
            }
          case None => false
        }
      }
    }
  }.toStream
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def unfold[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Option[(A, B)]): Stream[B] =
  f(a).map { case (a, b) => b #:: unfold(a)(f) }.getOrElse(Stream.empty)
```

This is correct and lazy (although some REPLs might attempt to print all the stream).

Scala streams have their `tail`s evaluated lazily. I don't think you can affect the tail of a stream in a lazy fashion in a tail-recursive way. However, it's pointless because laziness gives you stack safety:

```
assert(unfold(0) { _ => Some((0, 0)) } .toString == "Stream(0, ?)")
```

---

```
assert {
    try {
      unfold(0) { _ => Some((0, 0)) }.take(1000000).toList
      true
    } catch {
      case _: StackOverflowError => false
    }
  }
```